# Form Redirects before data is processed

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I am making a ASP.Net Core MVC with EntityFramework (Code First) Pattern. I have a razor page that renders a partial with all the form input (Removed most of divs easy to read). This is myPartial that on submit calls **AddClub** method in my controller

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddClub", "Club", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Club Sponser:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.TextBox("ClubSponser", null, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ClubSponser", placeholder = "Enter club Sponser" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-toolbar col-md-offset-7" role="group">
            <button type="submit" onsubmit="AddClub("ClubName","ClubOwner","ClubCoach","ClubSponser")" class="btn btn-primary">Add Club</button>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    }
```

This is my **Controller AddClub()**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddClub(string ClubName,string ClubOwner,string ClubCoach,string ClubSponser)
    {
        Club club = new Club()
        {
            Name = ClubName,
            Owner = ClubOwner,
            Coach=ClubCoach,
            Sponser=ClubSponser
        };
        clubRepo.AddClub(club);
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Club");
    }
```

This is my **Service Class** that implements Interface

```
   public async Task AddClub(Club club)
    {
        _context.Clubs.Add(club);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

In **Startup** Service is injected as Singleton

```
 services.AddSingleton<IClubRepo, ClubService>();
```

1) I believe that it is happening because In my service Class method is running asynchronously that might be the reason (Not sure). I have this hunch because If I don't redirect it updates database perfectly

2) I don't want to make another question but I just want an opinion if this is the correct way to submit form in ASP.Net core/MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await the action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddClub(string ClubName,string ClubOwner,string ClubCoach,string ClubSponser) {
    Club club = new Club() {
        Name = ClubName,
        Owner = ClubOwner,
        Coach=ClubCoach,
        Sponser=ClubSponser
    };
    await clubRepo.AddClub(club);
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Club");
}
```

In order to allow the save to complete before redirecting.